# How to fill table with missed dates in PostgreSQL with previous data

Tags: sql, postgresql, missing-data

I have a table:

| date | user_id | state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8/12/2021 | 1 | visit |
| 9/12/2021 | 1 | registered |
| 12/12/2021 | 1 | order |

In this table I only have updated of state of users, but I don't see the state by some particular date. How can I add rows with missing dates and fill them with previous value, so that the table will be:

| date | user_id | state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8/12/2021 | 1 | visit |
| 9/12/2021 | 1 | registered |
| 10/12/2021 | 1 | registered |
| 11/12/2021 | 1 | registered |
| 12/12/2021 | 1 | order |

Comment: Please share the query done till now

Comment: actually, I have no idea how to solve it so there are no query by now. I guess I can generate a series of dates, then left join, then with some window function fill with last value, but it won't work since I have a lot of users and there should be series of dates for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one attempt. The cte user_dates gets min and max dates for each user that is then fed to generate_series. I.e. each user is associated with all dates between there first and last date.

In the inner select we create a group for each first_value and consecutive null states.

In the outer select we pick the first_value for each such grp.

```
with user_dates(f, t, user_id) as (
  select min(T.dt), max(T.dt), user_id
  from T
  group by user_id
)
select user_id, dt, grp, first_value(state) over (partition by user_id, grp order by dt)
from (  
    select ud.user_id
         , cal.dt::date
         , state
         , count(T.state) over (partition by user_id
                                order by cal.dt) as grp
    from user_dates ud
    cross join generate_series(ud.f::timestamp, ud.t::timestamp , interval '1 day') cal (dt)
    left join T
        using (dt, user_id)
) as tmp 
order by user_id, dt
;
user_id dt  grp first_value
1   2021-12-08  1   visit
1   2021-12-09  2   registered
1   2021-12-10  2   registered
1   2021-12-11  2   registered
1   2021-12-12  3   order
```

You can remove grp from the select, it's merely there for informative purposes.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cCPI9wqd)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This code seems complicated for me, but I replaced T with my table_name and dt with created_at and run the code. It works, but only has first state in result table (visit). No other states are presented in result table. Is there any chance to fix your code with minimal time consumption?

Comment: Modify my fiddle with data that Illustrates the problem and update your question with the url and expected result

Comment: Modified your fiddle, check [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/r5Ijv3ra)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. The result in the third cell looks nothing like what you describe. You need to modify the insert in cell two with data that illustrates the problem.